# I want to build a docker image for my substrate node

Tags: substrate-node, docker

Now I am building a new docker image for my substrate node

`Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996`

`Node version v18.16.1`

I am using this `Dockerfile.dev` to build the docker image.

```
FROM paritytech/ci-linux:production as build

WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM ubuntu:22.04
WORKDIR /node

# Copy the node binary.
COPY --from=build /code/target/release/node-template .

# Install root certs, see: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/9984
# RUN apt update && \
#     apt install -y ca-certificates && \
#     update-ca-certificates && \
#     apt remove ca-certificates -y && \
#     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 9944
CMD [ "./node-template", "--dev" ]
```

By the way, I got this error and couldn't figure it out.

```
254.9 info: installing component 'rustfmt'
261.8     Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
648.1 error: failed to get `frame-benchmarking` as a dependency of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/code/node)`
648.1
648.1 Caused by:
648.1   failed to load source for dependency `frame-benchmarking`
648.1
648.1 Caused by:
648.1   Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#98f2e345
648.1
648.1 Caused by:
648.1   object not found - no match for id (98f2e3451c9143278ec53c6718940aeabcd3b68a); class=Odb (9); code=NotFound (-3)
------
Dockerfile.dev:5
--------------------
   3 |     WORKDIR /code
   4 |     COPY . .
   5 | >>> RUN cargo build --release
   6 |
   7 |     FROM ubuntu:22.04
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cargo build --release" did not complete successfully: exit code: 101
```

Any kind of answers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this commit (`#98f2e345`) might [no longer exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69516957) or you have a corrupt git registry.

After cloning the repo and checking, the commit does exist in the repository.

You can try deleting the cargo.lock or [clearing the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59881524).

Comment: Thank you, @forgetso. It was a good solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try clearing the registry @Ganesh11?

Comment: yes using this command `rm -rf ~/.cargo/registry`

Comment: @ganesh11's issue is not same as i posted

Comment: I make sure there is a technical critical error in @ganesh11's substrate node project.